# Unfortunately, "GoogleMapsV2" has stopped

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, google-maps-android-api-2

I am an android beginner, I've created a maps application by following a tutorial. I've downloaded all the required things for that app.

But when I run my application, it will give an error which says "Unfortunately 'GoogleMapsV2'has stopped". I researched a lot of blogs here and try each and every thing suggested by professionals but unfortunately their answers lead me nowhere the problem is still here.

P.S: I'm running this app on my Samsung Galaxy Grand.

here is the logcat.

```
03-17 14:36:29.468: D/jdwp(15645): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x3D
03-17 14:36:29.484: D/jdwp(15645): processIncoming
03-17 14:36:29.484: D/jdwp(15645): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13,
 id=0x4000028F, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8 
03-17 14:36:29.485: D/jdwp(15645): processIncoming 
03-17 14:36:29.485: D/jdwp(15645): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x17, id=0x40000290,flags=0x0, dataLen=0xC 
03-17 14:36:29.486: D/jdwp(15645): processIncoming 
03-17 14:36:29.487: D/jdwp(15645): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x40000291, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8 03-17 14:36:29.487: D/jdwp(15645): processIncoming 
03-17 14:36:29.488: D/jdwp(15645): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13,id=0x40000292, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8 
03-17 14:36:29.491: D/jdwp(15645): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x45 
03-17 14:36:29.493: W/asset(15645): AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
03-17 14:36:29.523: D/AndroidRuntime(15645): Shutting down VM 
03-17 14:36:29.523: W/dalvikvm(15645): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419759a8) 
03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.info/info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/info.androidhive.info-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/info.androidhive.info-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] 
03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269) 03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 
03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/info.androidhive.info-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/info.androidhive.info-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] 
03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 
03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    atjava.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 
03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054) 
03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
03-17 14:36:29.526: E/AndroidRuntime(15645):    ... 11 more
```

here is the manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="info.androidhive.info"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0"
         >

        <permission
            android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="12"
            android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <!-- Required to show current location -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

        <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <activity
                android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>


            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="my key" />
            <meta-data 
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

here is the .xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"  >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is main java file.

```
package info.androidhive.info;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line of code,

```
android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity"
```

to:

```
android:name="info.androidhive.info.MainActivity"
```

because package name is

```
package info.androidhive.info;
```

Remove:

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Now, the app is running but it's only showing a grid and zoom in and out buttons :(

Comment: @user3144474 regenerate the api key and check the settings in the google api console. code is alright after you follow suggested edit

Comment: @Raghunandan Sir , Please take a look Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451078/android-back-button-sign-not-showing-in-action-bar

Comment: thanks a lot sir. My application is perfectly running now. :)